# Confused with endianess: bits or bytes?

Tags: terminology, endianness, cpu-architecture

I extracted this from a tutorial:

> Little-Endian order is the one we will be using in  this document, and unless  stated specifically you should assume that Little-Endian order is used in any  file. The alternate is Big-Endian ordering.    So let’s see an example. Take the following stream or 8 bits    10001110  If you have been following the document  so far, you would quickly calculate  the value of this 8-bit number as being **1x2^7 + 0x2^6 + … + 1x2^1 + 0x2^0 = 142** This is an example of Little-Endian ordering. However, in Big-Endian ordering  we need to read the number in the opposite direction **1x2^0 + 0x2^1 + … + 1x2^6 + 0x2^7 = 113**

Is this correct?

I used to think that endianess has to do with order that the BYTES (not the bits) are read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the context of memory/storage, endianness indeed refers to **byte** ordering (typically).  What would it mean to say that e.g. the least-significant **bit** "comes first"?

Bit endianness is relevant in some situations, for instance when sending data over a serial bus.

Comment: In graphics memories, it can also be useful to consider bit endianness.  If you want to store 1, 8, 16, or 32 bit pixels in the same space, it's easiest to think of all of memory as a sequence of bits starting at zero, so the first byte (in 8-bit mode) is a sequence of bits 0 to 7, with 0 on the left.  (Which bit is most significant is a separate choice.)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - that quote you have there is rubbish, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make sense to reorder bits, and it would be pretty confusing to boot.  CPUs don't read simgle bits, they read bytes, or combinations of bytes, at one time, so that's the ordering that's important.

When they store a number made up of multiple bytes, they can either store it from left to right, making the high-order byte lowest in memory, or right to left, with the low-order byte lowest in memory.